# Add AngularJS expression to Google map embed

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to add an AngularJS expression to a Google Maps embed, here is my code:

```
<iframe width="240" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q={{Property.Address.Location.Latitude}},{{Property.Address.Location.Longitude}}&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

It does not display the correct values though.

Comment: I ended up using Angular Google Maps; https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use [**`ng-src`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of `src`?

```
<iframe width="240" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" ng-src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q={{Property.Address.Location.Latitude}},{{Property.Address.Location.Longitude}}&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

---

**From Angular ngSrc documentation**

> Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   `{{hash}}` until Angular replaces the expression inside `{{hash}}`. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.